# How to dump an advanced revelation database?

Tags: export, dump

Retail store I work with has an ancient inventory/accounting/receiving system that is based off [Advanced Revelation](http://www.revelation.com/).  They run the DOS and Windows clients.  I'd like to get a dump of their data to work on migration or at least create other views of their data, without paying $$$ for the vendor do to this service.

I can find very little documentation of Advanced revelation.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Advanced Revelation is a multi-valued database based on the original PICK operating system.  You can find information on PICK and it's spin-offs here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick_operating_system

I've been developing on PICK and like systems for over 35 years, including Advanced Revelation.  Manuals are a little difficult to find online. You may also have some luck finding more information here:

http://www.jes.com

Answer (score -1):

I have developed software which will automate the extraction of all Revelation, Advanced Revelation (Arev) and OpenInsight data. No knowledge of these platforms or a functioning system is required. All that is necessary is the .LK and .OV data files.
This is the link:
https://www.exportr.co.nz/
or contact me at the Gmail account for jocelyn.amon

Comment: I'm not gona join in the downvoting, as this could be a lifeline for someone who's stuck trying to dump out an old arev database. @JocelynAmon -- if you posted this as a comment you'd avoid getting downvoted!